# Function with compact level set are lower semi continuous.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $I:\mathbb R^n\to [0,\infty ]$ a function s.t. $$\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid I(x)\leq M\}$$
is compact. Prove that $I$ is lower semi-continuous and $I$ reach his infimum.

---

I denote $\mathcal B(a,r )$ the ball centered at $a\in\mathbb R^n$ and of radius $r>0$.

**My proof :** Let $\varepsilon >0$ and set $$A_\varepsilon :=\{x\in \mathbb R^n\mid I(x)\leq I(x_0)-\varepsilon \}.$$ Then $A_\varepsilon $ is a closed set that do not contain $x_0$.  Therefore, there is $\delta >0$ s.t. $\mathcal B(x_0,\delta )\subset A_\varepsilon ^c$. Therefore,
$$I(x)>I(x_0)-\varepsilon ,$$
for all $x\in \mathcal B(x_0,\delta )$, and thus
$$\inf_{\mathcal B(x_0,\delta )}I(x)\geq I(x_0)-\varepsilon .$$

Consequently $$\liminf_{x\to x_0 }I(x)=\lim_{\delta >0}\inf_{\mathcal B(x_0,\delta )}I(x)\geq I(x_0)-\varepsilon .$$
Since the result hold for all $\varepsilon >0$, we get $$\liminf_{x\to x_0}I(x)\geq I(x_0).$$

Since the result hold for all $x_0\in\mathbb R^n$, the claim follow.

**Q1)** Is my proof correct ?

**Q2)** I didn't succeed to prove that $I$ reach it minimum, any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First part is correct.

There exists $(x_j)$ such that $I(x_j)$ converges to the infimum of $I$, say $m$. Now $x_j \in \{x: I(x) \leq M\}$ eventually for any $M > m$. By hypothesis, $(x_j)$ has a subsequence $(x_{j_i})$ converging to some point $z$. Now $I(z) \leq \lim \inf I(x_{j_i})=m$ so $I(z)$  is equal to the infimum $m$.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, your proof for question $1$ is correct, and quite elegant. As a stylistic note, I'd recommend writing something like "Suppose $x_0 \in \Bbb{R}^n$" before launching into the rest of the proof, just so it's clear before the end of the proof that $x_0$ is an arbitrary element of $\Bbb{R}^n$. This is just a suggestion though.

For part 2, refer to [Cantor's Intersection Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_intersection_theorem) for compact sets. If $m$ is the infimal value of $I$, then we can express
$$I^{-1}\{m\} = \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb{N}} I^{-1}\left[m, m + \frac{1}{n}\right],$$
where the right hand side is a intersection of nested compact non-empty lower level sets, and hence is non-empty.